# Regular Update vs DBMS Parallel execute

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have recently learned DBMS Parallel execute functionality. I tried to test the performance of DBMS parallel execute with the regular update statement. I don't see the performance improvement over the regular update statement. Is there something is missing. Attaching the sample code details.The table consists of 7,020 rows.

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
  l_try      NUMBER;
  l_status   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  -- Create the TASK
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_TASK ('mytask');
  -- Chunk the table by ROWID
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_ROWID('mytask', 'REVPRO_1001', 'RPRO_RC_LINE_G', true, 1000);
  -- Execute the DML in parallel
  l_sql_stmt := 'update /*+ ROWID (dda) */ RPRO_RC_LINE_G e       
                  SET e.NUM2 = 100    
                  WHERE rowid BETWEEN :start_id AND :end_id';

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK('mytask', l_sql_stmt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE, parallel_level => 5);
  -- If there is an error, RESUME it for at most 2 times.
  L_try      := 0;
  L_status   := DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.TASK_STATUS('mytask');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Status'||L_status);
  WHILE(l_try < 2 AND L_status != DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.FINISHED)
  LOOP
    L_try := l_try + 1;
    DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RESUME_TASK('mytask');
    L_status := DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.TASK_STATUS('mytask');
  END LOOP;
  -- Done with processing; drop the task
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.DROP_TASK('mytask');
END;
```

The above block takes Elapsed time: 00:00:03.315 to update the table.

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE /*+ ROWID (dda) */
    RPRO_RC_LINE_G e SET e.NUM2 = 100 ;
END;
```

Whereas when I update the same table with simple SQL query, It takes elapsed time  00:00:00.370.

Which is 3 seconds faster than the DBMS parallel execute. Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is surely a certain amount of overhead in creating the tasks and managing the dbms_scheduler jobs, and for the tiny number of rows in your test, the plain `update` has less work to do.

I tried it with a million rows, and the plain `update` took consistently 36 seconds to complete, while the `dbms_parallel_execute` version varied from 36 seconds to 9 seconds. (This is on my laptop where I was not expecting much gain from parallel execution. My `cpu_count` = 2, `parallel_threads_per_cpu` = 2. I saw completion in 6 seconds using 8 threads.)

Answer (score 0):

So the simple non-parallel update is about 9 times faster. Seems as if the update is limited by disk speed, not CPU. I'm guessing if `SET e.NUM2 = 100` was instead `SET e.NUM2 = some_heavy_calculation()` the parallel solution would be faster. At least if the calculation is heavy enough and CPU-bound. Your Oracle server could also be configured not to take advantage of more than one CPU kernel. Run `show parameters` as DBA (or user `system`) to see if the parameters `cpu_count` and `parallel_threads_per_cpu` is set to 1. Or check if your old(?) CPU in fact only have one kernel. Try to change `parallel_level=>5` into `NULL` or `2` or some other number. 5 could be too many.